# Pandas converting mixed datatype column to float

Tags: pandas, python-3.8

I have a dataframe with one column as follows:

```
df['mixed'].values
array([' GC', '345', '69', '28-'], dtype=object)
```

I tried the following:

```
df['mixed'].astype(float, errors='ignore')
```

But it doesn't do anything. I was expecting the following:

```
df['mixed'].values
array([' GC', 345, 69, '28-'], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `pd.to_numeric`

```
pd.to_numeric(df['mixed'],errors='coerce').fillna(df['mixed']).tolist()
[' GC', 345.0, 69.0, '28-']
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is an error during the conversion the original object will be returned. The [documentation for `astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) [emphasis mine]:

> errors{‘raise’, ‘ignore’}, default ‘raise’
> Control raising of exceptions on invalid data for provided dtype.
>
> - raise : allow exceptions to be raised
> - ignore : suppress exceptions. **On error return original object.**

To obtain the expected output, you can instead use [`to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) and setting `errors='coerce'` which will set any invalid rows to `NaN`. These can then be set to the original value using `fillna` ([see the answer by BENY](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69248509/7579547)).